# replace/ encode < and > with jquery/ ajax before submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code which is part of a comment form in a page.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/script.php",
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        $('#comment_form').fadeOut(1000);
        var url = 'path/to/script.php';
        $('#commenti').load(url + ' .comment');    
    }
});
```

On server side all characters like `<` and `>` get stripped but i need them to allow displaying code snippets inside the `<code></code>` tags.

Is there any way with jquery to convert the `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;` *before* submitting so the comments will display without stripped characters?

Comment: Why not do it at the server side? That seems much more easy than stripping them away.

Comment: I need to do it on client side due to some reasons. Looking for a good solution for ours without success :-(

Comment: What solutions have you found that were not good, and why? This problem doesn't seem to be that complex, or am I missing something?

Comment: So far i haven't found any solution. If i had found one, i woudn't ask this question. I need to convert the characters before submitting.

Comment: Just take them out of the object that `serialize` returns (you know which fields to encode), then replace the characters you need to replace (e.g. with regex), then set them in the object that you send as data?

Comment: sanitize on the server upon upload, anyone can send un-escaped garbage by disabling JS, and if that's all you count on, it's an XSS waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any good client side solution yet, so here is a little php-serverside function.
For anyone who needs it:

```
function specialchars($special) {
$replace = array(
'<' => '&lt;',
'>' => '&gt;',
'&' => '&amp;'
 );
return strtr($special, $replace);
}
```

Use the function *specialchars* based on your needs.

Comment: If you're doing it on the server side (as you should), why not just use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function htmlEncode(value){
  //create a in-memory div, set it's inner text(which jQuery automatically encodes)
  //then grab the encoded contents back out.  The div never exists on the page.
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(value){
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}
```

and take a look at this post [HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: I've found this post ours ago but i don't know how to integrate it inside the ajax call..

Answer (score 0):

**Using jQuery**, you can retrieve a string with < and > replaced by html-entities by using this approach.

```
var text = "<script>alert('I am XSS');<script> This is regular ol' text!";
var escapedText = $('<i>').text(text).html();
// "&lt;script&gt;alert('I am XSS');&lt;script&gt; This is regular ol' text!"
```

The output might need additional escaping when posting however, due to the ampersands *(?querystring=string&string2=...)*

I would recommend you escape the <> characters with encodeURIComponent, and do post-processing on the server, like others have suggested previously:

```
var text = "<script>alert('I am XSS');<script> This is regular ol' text!";
var escapedText = encodeURIComponent(text);
// "%3Cscript%3Ealert('I%20am%20XSS')%3B%3Cscript%3E%20This%20is%20regular%20ol'%20text!"
// post with AJAX
```

then on the server

```
echo htmlentities(rawurldecode($_POST["query"]));
// "&lt;script&gt;alert('I am XSS');&lt;script&gt; This is regular ol' text!"
```

If your app is facing the WWW, you ought to ensure all input is being properly sanitized before being output to users - [OWASP Encoding Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Encoding_Project) and [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) are worth checking out!